# What's wrong with this configuration in Jetty? Unable to run any context

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

Here is my code-

```
    Server server = new Server();
    ServerConnector pxy = new ServerConnector(server);
    pxy.setPort(8080);
    server.addConnector(pxy);

    HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();

    ServletContextHandler test1 = new ServletContextHandler(handlers, "/test1", ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);
    ServletContextHandler test2 = new ServletContextHandler(handlers, "/test2", ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);


    ServletHolder rootServletHolder = new ServletHolder(root.class);      
    test1.addServlet(rootServletHolder, "/test1/*");

    ServletHolder testServletHolder = new ServletHolder(test.class);      
    test2.addServlet(testServletHolder, "/test2/*");


    server.setHandler(handlers);
    server.start();
    server.join();
```

When I go to http://domainName.com:8080/test1 or http://domainName.com:8080/test2 I get not found error message.

Jetty start-up  looks like this-

> 2013-06-07 18:58:59.871:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.0.3.v20130506
>   2013-06-07 18:58:59.895:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7c87c24a{/test1,null,AVAILABLE}
>   2013-06-07 18:58:59.896:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@34e4c825{/test2,null,AVAILABLE}
>   2013-06-07 18:58:59.919:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@3932f2b2{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration has a context of `"/test1"` and a servlet under that of `"/test1/*"`

That means your URL would be http://domainName.com:8080/test1/test1/

Just think this way and it'll make sense.

- ServletContextHandler == WebApp
- ServletContextHandler.addServlet() == add a servlet to that WebApp

I think what you want is a single ServletContextHandler on say `"/"` and have 2 servlets added to it.

example:

```java
Server server = new Server();
ServerConnector pxy = new ServerConnector(server);
pxy.setPort(8080);
server.addConnector(pxy);

// Use ContextHandlerCollection 
ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
// Don't forget to add it to the server!
server.setHandler(contexts);

ServletContextHandler testApp = new ServletContextHandler(contexts, "/",
    ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);

ServletHolder rootServletHolder = new ServletHolder(root.class);      
ServletHolder testServletHolder = new ServletHolder(test.class);      

testApp.addServlet(rootServletHolder, "/test1/*");
testApp.addServlet(testServletHolder, "/test2/*");


server.setHandler(handlers);
server.start();
server.join();
```

Also, take a look around the embedded jetty examples.  The [ManyServletContext.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/ManyServletContexts.java) seems most relevant.

Comment: Thank you! I was actually using two contexts so that I can set-up basic authentication in Jetty in context only while leaving the other one for anonymous access.